# create/register a user using laravel3 + sentry1

Tags: laravel, laravel-3, cartalyst-sentry

I'd like to register a user without metadata. I have this code but this

```
$user = Sentry::user()->register(array(
     'email' => Input::get('email'),
     'password' => Input::get('password')
));
```

but then I got this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'first_name' doesn't have a default value
>
> SQL: INSERT INTO `users_metadata` (`user_id`) VALUES (?)
>
> Bindings: array (
>     0 => 1,
>   )

I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL error suggests, that you have a field `first_name`in the table `users_metadata`, that is required. According to the source on [github](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/blob/1.1/master/sentry/user.php#L316), metadata is optional on the create method.

I would check if the field `first_name` has allowed NULL values, and if not, allow it.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. You are right. first_name doesn't allow null values and I know why this error is been thrown but then I ask you this: do I have to update/change the migrations according to what I'm needing for my app?

Comment: If you don't want to insert first_name's you have to allow NULL's and therefore change your migrations, yes.